# XAMPP Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I just installed XAMPP and when I press start for MySQL, it started normally, and then suddenly it stopped. 
Here what I got in the console:

```
12:52:45 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:52:45 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:52:45 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:52:45 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:52:45 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:52:45 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:52:45 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

And here is in the error log file:

```
Version: '5.6.24'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-22 10:01:43 12f0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 39662092 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-10-22 10:01:43 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 39662092
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-10-22 10:01:44 7700 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-10-22 10:01:45 7700 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-10-22 10:01:45 7700 [Note] mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.24'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Can anyone help me? I should get back to work with this XAMPP. Thanks before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF You're using Linux/Unix, try to manually start mysql by running mysqld in the lampp folder and see if this works or not?